# inter word space not printing in a tags tab of tagged pdf, how to insert the inter word space?

Tags: xetex, accessibility, tagpdf

I am trying to create a tagpdf, with the reading order of footnotes should read, after read footnote citation, so i have tagged the coding in the tex file through

```
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
```

i am getting reading order, but the inter word space is missing in the tag, even i used like below in the image

\tagpdfsetup{activate,interwordspace=true}

[image]

i am using xelatex for producing pdf. How to insert the inter word space in the tag

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{uncompress,debug={para=view}}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}

\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{
 activate,
 interwordspace=true,
 }

\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage[pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,hyperfootnotes=false,
            ]{hyperref}

 \hypersetup{colorlinks}
 
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}


\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
A patient seeking treatment may have a triage interview interrupted for myriad reasons, often for reasons unrelated to patient care . Such interruptions in the\tagmcend\tagstructend\footnote{\tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}11111111 Footnote text Footnote text\tagstructend\tagmcend}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}triage process can generate challenges in the present and future care of the patient, including distracting nurses from collecting appropriate data; lower-quality or inaccurate triage decisions (e.g. due to a missed symptom identification or incomplete assessment); rework for nurses dueto forgetting; delays in care
000000\tagmcend\tagstructend\footnote{\tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}22222222222 Footnote text 33333333 Footnote text\tagstructend\tagmcend}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}and potential increases\vspace*{0.5pt} in morbidity or mortality.
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
There is a compelling need to understand how triage interruptions 666666666666666666\tagmcend\tagstructend\footnote{\tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}4444444444444 Footnote text 555555555555 Footnote text\tagstructend\tagmcend}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P} affect patient satisfaction and perceptions of care. Several studies have examined\vspace*{0.4pt} the effects of interruptions on specific tasks or persons but have yet to fully evaluate their impact on patients' satisfaction and their perceptions of care quality. While some studies found links between interruptions and decreased patient satisfaction, others  found that associations between interruptions and patient perception of overall ED quality were based on the source and reason for the interruption. However, none of the studies looking at patient perceptions of care were based on the triage interview. Therefore, the aim of this study was to identify how the frequency and duration of interruptions during triage affect patient satisfaction and the patient's perception of the care they received.
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=Sect}
\tagstructbegin{tag=H}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H}
\section{Methods}\def\thesubsection{}
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=Sect}
\tagstructbegin{tag=H}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H}
\subsection{Design}
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
A prospective, observational, cohort study design was used to examine the effect of triage interruptions on patient care. Local Institutional Review Board approval was obtained. We conducted time-and-motion observations of both nurse triage interviews and initial physician assessments as they occurred in the ED. Prior to conducting observations, consent was obtained from emergency care providers and then these providers each completed a questionnaire. Immediately following each observation, patients were approached to complete a survey about their triage experience and to permit the research team to review their medical records after their discharge. Each provider and patient participant were assigned a unique identifier at time of consent. The data collector recorded provider's and patient's identifier at the time of data collection on all data collection instruments. Consistency of data extraction was verified on every tenth record by the first author.
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=Sect}
\tagstructbegin{tag=H}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H}
\subsection{Study setting and participants}
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
Data collection occurred in a 728 bed, academic, Level 1 trauma center located in the midwestern USA with 55 ED beds seeing approximately 75\,000 adult patients per year. ED nurses, physicians and patients were invited to participate. Patients were excluded if they were (i) a member of a vulnerable population (i.e. under age 18, incarcerated, cognitive impairment), (ii) assigned an Emergency Severity Index (ESI) of 1 (high acuity), (iii) non-English speakers or (iv) declined to participate.
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=Sect}
\tagstructbegin{tag=H}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H}
\subsection{Data collection instruments}
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
\textit{Provider Questionnaires} were completed by nurses, physicians, physician's assistants and nurse practitioners during times when patient care was not occurring (beginning of shift, at the nurse's station, in the breakroom). The questionnaire included demographic questions, work experience, ED role and provider's perceptions of the effect of interruptions on patient care.
\tagmcend
\tagstructend

\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
\textit{The Triage Interruptions Assessment Tool (TIAT)} was used to measure interruptions. This 66-item instrument with eight subscales is used to measure interruptions in clinical practice and facilitates recording of (i) \textit{source of interruption} (person initiating interruption); (ii) \textit{cause of interruption} (mechanism of interrupting); (iii) \textit{task interrupted}; (iv) \textit{provider's reaction to the interruption}; (v) \textit{potential impact of interruption on patient outcomes}; (vi) \textit{errors;} (vii) \textit{duration of triage}; and (viii) \textit{duration of interruption}.\break{} This information was collected for every interruption that occurred during the triage interview. The TIAT has strong content validity (CVI\,\ensuremath{=}\,0.91) and interrater reliability (Cohen's kappa\,\ensuremath{=}\,0.773) and has been validated in adult EDs for triage interviews occurring in a designated triage interview area or stretcher-side.
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend


\end{document}
```

Comment: xelatex doesn't support interword spaces. Use lualatex.

Comment: side remark: with a current latex and tagpdf paragraph tagging should be automatic.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer when using automatic tag the footnote reading order is changed at the end of the page

Comment: Yes, there are places where you will to disable it. But it can safe you much typing nevertheless.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i didnt  used before luatex, what is the advantage comparing to xelatex

Comment: well the advantage for you is that interword space will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interword space glyphs require lualatex (best) or pdflatex (ok). With xelatex it won't work.